# Converting integer to timestamp in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have a simple table with 3 columns

id,
timestamp,
username

id is int
timestamp is int
username is varchar

I am trying to get those timestamps to either a date format or a proper timestamp to use it in a dataset, but I might be missing something here since the "year" part is not showing properly.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
select

table.id,
table.timestamp,
to_timestamp(table.timestamp),
table.username

from table
```

[image]

````
select

table.id,
table.timestamp,
to_char(to_timestamp(table.timestamp), 'dd-mm-yyyy'),
table.username

from table```
````

Comment: I found the solution:

 select to_timestamp(table.timestamp/ 1000)::date;

Comment: You'd have to share a sample `int`-based timestamp that you're referring to. If that's "an epoch", then it's usually the number of microseconds since 1 January 1970. See [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xs-60UO7)

Comment: `timestamp is int`, why don't you store a timestamp as a timestamp? (with or without the time zone) You can convert the column using ALTER TABLE

Comment: Could you post sample source data? This information is not sufficient to work on a solution

Comment: I found the solution as stated in another comment:

select to_timestamp(table.timestamp/ 1000)::date;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution as stated in another comment:

```
    select to_timestamp(table.timestamp/ 1000)::date;
```